# Should the Output RGB be Divided by Output Alpha in the Non-premultiplied Alpha Blending Equation?

Tags: opengl, shader, alpha, alphablending, blending

In [alpha compositing wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing), I see the blending equation is like this (no pre-multiplying):

[image: equation0]

But in [this slides](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2007_fall/Lectures/blending.pdf), the equation is like this:

[image: equation1]

In the first equation, `outRGB` is divided by `outAlpha`.
What does it mean? Which one is the correct equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first formula with division is correct. The second one is either wrong or is designed to take non-premultiplied colors and produce premultiplied ones.

Anyway, it's pretty easy to derive the non-premultiplied formula from the premultiplied one, which happens to be very simple and intuitive:

```
blended = front + back * (1.0 - front.a);
```

The intuition is: we take the front color and add a bit of the back color to it, namely as much as we can see through the front color.

The non-premultiplied version will then be:

```
blended.a = front.a + back.a * (1.0 - front.a);
blended.rgb = (front.rgb * front.a + back.rgb * back.a * (1.0 - front.a)) / blended.a;
```

Note that this formula, as well as the ones you presented assumes alpha to be in the range of [0, 1] rather than [0, 255].

Comment: But in OpenGL/WebGL, the non-premultiplied function is like this:`gl.blendEquationSeparate( gl.FUNC_ADD, gl.FUNC_ADD );
     gl.blendFuncSeparate( gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );` So it's `blended.rgb = front.rgb * front.a + back.rgb * (1 - front.a)`. It's different from the above equation you mentioned. Why?

Comment: That formula only works with a fully opaque background, that is back.a == 1. OpenGL's blending machinery simply can't handle the general "translucent A over translucent B" case for non-premultiplied colors.